# Integration through procedure Oracle

Tags: stored-procedures, integration, oracle12c

I would like to integrate with OSB keeping my logic in the DB. To minimize bandwidth load and calls to DB I would like to batch insert records through a Stored Procedure.
my goal -> avoid loops on procedure, avoid cursor, avoid multi call to DB.

In TSQL I would have done this through Table type parameter, but as this is not possible in PLSQL I have created the following script that gives me error on parameter select in the package body. Can anyone help me?:

```
--create type object
create or replace TYPE "Type_test" IS OBJECT (
id                     number(20,0)                
oppdateringstype       VARCHAR2(50)
)
;

-- Create package head
create or replace package test as 
type t_input_table is table of Type_test index by binary_integer;
procedure Proc (p_input_table in t_input_table);
end;

--Create package body
create or replace package body test as 
procedure Proc(p_input_table in t_input_table)
as
BEGIN
 --Some logic select * from p_input_table
 end;
```

Comment: Add `table()`: `select * from table(p_input_table)`